# How do I get all the betas from a specified production function?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, econometrics, stata

$$Q_i = a L_i^{\beta_1} K_i^{\beta_2}\exp\left(\beta_3 L_i + \beta_4 K_i\right)$$

The above is the given production function and I'm supposed to find the coefficient values in Stata through regression. However, what I know is that when I use

```
regress lout llab lcap
```

where `lout` `llab` and `lcap` are the linearized output, labor and capital, I would only have two betas. I'm sure I've done something wrong, I'm not sure what to do anymore.

Comment: Although software-specific questions are off-topic here, I can tell you that even if your variables are $\log Q, \log L, \log K$ what you are fitting is only a linearized version of $Q   = a  L^{\beta_1} K^{\beta_2}$ and so getting two coefficient estimates is exactly what you asked from Stata (other than the intercept). (Not a good idea on CV to assume that the typical reader is an economist familiar with such functions.)

Answer (score 4):

Your meaning of "linearized" appears to be a model for $\log Q$ (plus an additive error $\varepsilon$), which according to the laws of logarithms would be

$$\eqalign{
\log Q &= \log\left(a L^{\beta_1} K^{\beta_2}\exp\left(\beta_3 L + \beta_4 K\right)\right)+\varepsilon \\
&= \log a + \beta_1 \log L + \beta_2 \log K + \beta_3 L + \beta_4 K + \varepsilon.
}$$

You could fit it by regressing $\log Q$ against the *four* variables $(\log L, \log K, L, K)$ (plus an intercept).  The estimate of $a$ will be the exponential of the estimated intercept $\widehat{\log a}.$